How to override "signInName" with "mail" for email-based 2FA using custom policy?
I am using this sample policy from Microsoft as the starting point to implement 2FA using email address.  In the sample policy, they copy the SignInName value into the ReadOnlyClaim claim in the first step of the orchestration.
However, what I need to do is instead us the Mail field from B2C, so I'm trying to figure out how to copy the Mail field into the ReadOnlyEmail claim early in the orchestration, so that it will be used instead of SignInName when performing email-based 2FA.
Step 3 of the orchestration is where we query AD for additional fields. I am able to successfully pull back the Mail property in this step.
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
      <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>


So I created a Step 4 to copy the Mail property into the ReadOnlyEmail field.  However, it seems that this value never gets set and I can't figure out why.
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADCopyMailToReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TpCopyMailToReadOnlyEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<TechnicalProfile Id="TpCopyMailToReadOnlyEmail">
  <DisplayName>Copy the Mail attribute to the ReadOnlyEmail attribute.</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mail" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mail" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyMailToReadOnlyEmail" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>

  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyMailToReadOnlyEmail" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
   <InputClaims>
     <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mail" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
   </InputClaims>
   <InputParameters>
     <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
   </InputParameters>
   <OutputClaims>
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
   </OutputClaims>
 </ClaimsTransformation>

But every time the EmailVerifyOnSignIn technical profile executes, the readOnlyEmail claim continues to contain the SignInName, not the Mail property that I'm trying to override it with.

If you do an OutputClaimsTransformations in a TP, you need to output the OutputClaimsTransformations value in the TP as well.
In the TP, add a:
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />


When I add your suggested output claim, I get an unhandled 500 exception after I login (presumably when the Tp executes).  Could there potentially be a type mismatch or something?  The mail field is an email., but I'm presuming this a string just like ReadOnlyEmail?

I suggest looking at the logs to see the exact error - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

In AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId, what output claim are you using to get mail? Are you using "otherMails". This is a string collection not a string
